# is there a way to present a view controller already loaded?

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller

i have an app with 5 views, mostly consisting of drill downs.

lets say i drill down to the 4th view controller. is there a way to present the second view controller exactly as it is without recreating it and modally present that view?

the drill downs do a sort of round about and i dont want to force the user to reselect their selection on the first view to bring them into the second view

so its like this (tvc = tableviewcontroller)

```
tvc1 > tvc2 > tvc3 > tvc4 > tvc2 > tvc5
         ^                   ^
         these two views are the same view in memory
```

Comment: Is there a technical reason you can't use UINavigationController?  That sounds a lot like what you want here.

Comment: Its sounds like potentially a deficiency in the way tvc2 is implemented - can't it remember and act upon the state of the input from the user? In other words cache the user's selection state and tvc2's display reflects that selection state?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot present tvc2 again while it is already in the "stack" of presented view controllers.

If you push your view controllers onto a navigation controller's stack, then you can change the order of the view controllers in that stack by assigning to its `viewControllers` property or by sending it `setViewControllers:animated:`. You can hide its navigation bar if you don't want users to see it. I don't think it's safe to put the same view controller into the stack in two places at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

You can possibly iterate over the visible viewControllers, and use the `is` casting operator to check if it is that type of class. Then find the view controller and pop to it.

Objective-C

```
for (id viewController in self.navigationController.viewControllers) {
    if ([viewController isKindOfClass:[ViewControllerClass class]]) {
        [self.navigationController popToViewController:viewController animated:TRUE];
    }
}
```

Swift 2.0

```
for viewController in self.navigationController!.viewControllers {
    if viewController is ViewControllerClass {             
        self.navigationController?.popToViewController(viewController, animated: true)
    }
}
```

Comment: im coding in obj-c

Comment: @lizzy81I just updated the answer for both Obj-C and Swift

Answer (score 0):

`UINavigationController` has an array called `viewControllers`. This will give you the list of `UIViewControllers` that exist in that navigation stack.

You can try something like:

```
UIViewController *yourTableViewController = [self.navigationController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:(theIndexOfYourTableViewController)];
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: would 'yourTableViewController' have the same properties as it was when it was tvc2? lets say for example i changed the tableview cell color for only tvc2, would that color still be present? just left for work, cant test till much later